# Clear local variables

Tags: assembly, x86

When I call a function that receive arguments, the own function clear the pushed data with "add esp, n" and the local variables with POPs, OK.

When I call a function that receive pointers (address) or when I call a syscall that receive pointers... How these functions/syscalls clear the parameters in the stack? The data pointed can be in the the stack or in the heap.
For example:

```
push edx         ; NULL    ;
push 0x68732f6e  ; "n/sh"  ; "//bin/sh\0"
push 0x69622f2f  ; "//bi"  ;
mov ebx, esp     ; ebx = &"//bin/sh\0"
push edx         ; NULL
push ebx         ; &"//bin/sh\0"
mov ecx, esp     ; ecx = args[&"//bin/sh\0", NULL]
push edx         ; NULL
mov edx, esp     ; edx = envp[NULL]

int 0x80
```

Source example that need execute RET:

```
BITS 32

section .text
global _start
_start:
    call Foo

    ; exit
    mov ebx, 0
    mov eax, 1
    int 0x80

Foo:
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp

    ; Create the socket file descriptor
    ; int socket(int domain, int type, int protocol)

    mov al, 102  ; __NR_socketcall
    mov bl, 1    ; __NR_socketcall type (socket)

    ; socket parameters
    sub esp, 8    ; sin_zero
    push 6        ; IPPROTO_TCP
    push 1        ; SOCK_STREAM
    push 2        ; AF_INET
    mov ecx, esp  ; &uargs

    int 0x80  ; socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)

    ; add esp, 0
    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp
    ret
```

Answer (score 4):

If a function or a system call expects a pointer to data that is located on the stack or on the heap it will certainly not *clean up* those data. It would only remove the pointer to such data if the calling protocol required it.

Comment: I've added a source as example. Stack isn't cleaned. This data is tracted as trash and always is located in the stack? How ret know where jump? ret = jmp [ebp+4]?

Comment: The only RET in this example will return to the instruction below *call Foo*. There really is no stack wizardry involved. Every PUSH made **within** *Foo* is removed by the epilog code `mov esp,ebp`.

Comment: the `ret` in your code will get the return address from the stack: `pop eip, [esp]` and `add esp, 4`. In your code this [esp] will be the adress to the instruction `mov ebx, 0`, which is executed after your `call Foo`. This address was put on the stack by the `cal` opcode